# I ate gelatin without knowing, what do I do?

Tags: sharia, pork

I am a recently converted Muslim. I usually read the ingredients on everything I pick up, especially that in which contains jelly texture and frosting. Previously I got sick and was worried that I had bad breath so I picked out some breathe mints without reading the ingredients. After eating a second piece (it was Altoids) I started readying the ingredients and threw the mints away as soon as I read gelatin. I am afraid I have sinned. Even though I did not know.

What steps should I take to ask Allah for forgiveness? Should I throw up the mints right away, prepare wadu, and pray? Or should I just ask Allah to forgive me with a dua?

Answer (score 1):

In the name of *Allah*

Nothing on you brother. Allah Exalted is He and high above said:

> Allah does not charge a soul except [with that within] its capacity. It will have [the consequence of] what [good] it has gained, and it will bear [the consequence of] what [evil] it has earned. "Our Lord, do not impose blame upon us if we have forgotten or erred. Our Lord, and lay not upon us a burden like that which You laid upon those before us. Our Lord, and burden us not with that which we have no ability to bear. And pardon us; and forgive us; and have mercy upon us. You are our protector, so give us victory over the disbelieving people."
>   Surat Al-Baqarah (The Cow) 2:286

ِAnd Prophet Muhammed Peace Be Upon Him said:

> ["Allah has forgiven my nation for mistakes and forgetfulness, and what they are forced to do."](http://sunnah.com/urn/1321240)

So nothing on you, except you have to wash your mouth and hands from it because it is impure.